# objShell.Run MailTo populate vars

Tags: vbscript

I have a script I’m trying to run that will grab the IP address and Computer name and popup their default mail client.  I can’t figure out how to have the mailto grab the variables..  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 

    Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("Process") 
    strComputer = objEnv("COMPUTERNAME") 
    strUser = "Scanner.User" 
    strPass = "SomePassword" 

    Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & ",computer") 

    Set objUser = colAccounts.Create("user", strUser) 

    objUser.SetPassword strPass 

    Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000 
    objPasswordExpirationFlag = ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD 
    objUser.Put "userFlags", objPasswordExpirationFlag 

    objUser.SetInfo 

    Set Group = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrators,group") 
    Group.Add(objUser.ADspath) 

    temp = "select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration "& _ 
    "where IPEnabled=TRUE" 

    temp2 = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" 

    set IPConfigSet = GetObject(temp2).ExecQuery(temp) 

    for each IPConfig in IPConfigSet 
     if Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) then 
        for i=LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) to UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) 

            objShell.Run("mailto:MyEmail@address.com&subject=strComputer&body=IPConfig.IPAddress(i)") 
           Msgbox IPConfig.IPAddress(i) 
        next 
     end if 
    next
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ampersand ([VBScript's Concatenation Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) to generate your mailto URI.

```
objShell.Run("mailto:MyEmail@address.com&subject=" & strComputer & "&body=" & IPConfig.IPAddress(i))
```